# Derive two new columns using join condition but conditions are different for columns

Tags: sql

```
Table A
id,key,roll_no
-------------
1,100,10
2,105|101,20
=====================
Table B
key_1,key_2
----------
100,102
105,101
```

conditions are to join and get two columns
#col_1=> A.id , where A.key=B.key_1 and A.roll_no=10
#col_2=> A.id , where A.key=(B.key_1 | B.key_2) and A.roll_no=20
for col_2 we need to merger key_1 and _key_2 columns of table B to get the join key
I can build columns individually but facing issue to build both the column in a single column.

```
col_1
========
select A.id as Col_1
from TABLE_A A INNER JOIN  TABLE_B B
where A.key=B.key_1
and  A.roll_no=10

col_2
=======
select A.id as Col_2
from TABLE_A A INNER JOIN TABLE_B B
where A.key=(concat(B.key_1,'|',B.key_2))
and  A.roll_no=20
```

I can build columns individually but facing issue to build both the column in a single query as where condition is different for both.
Expected ouyput will be

```
col_1,col_2
-----------
1,2
```

Comment: *A.roll_no=20* doesn't exist on your example ?

Comment: Strat reading up on JOIN instead of commas, then you will find an answer

Comment: [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) you really should have kicked by now

Comment: @Ergest Basha
One value was missed . I have added

Comment: Yes @ErgestBasha

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (I'd expect a syntax error for a `JOIN` without an `ON`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note* I strongly do not recommend doing it in a real world application.

One option would be using row_number() which a lot of dbms does support.

The following example is based on MySQL but I thinks it can work in other dbms as well

Try,

```
with first_col as (
  select A.id as Col_1,row_number() over (order by A.id) as row_num
  from TableA A 
   inner join TableB B on A.key=B.key_1
   and  A.roll_no=10
), second_col as (
   select A.id as Col_2 ,row_number() over (order by A.id) as row_num
   from TableA A 
   inner join TableB B on A.key=(concat(B.key_1,'|',B.key_2))
   and  A.roll_no=20
) select fc.Col_1,
         sc.Col_2
  from second_col sc 
  inner join first_col fc on fc.row_num=sc.row_num
```

Result,

```
Col_1   Col_2
  1       2
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/5vV1xYpJ)

Comment: any other approach can you think of ?
is it ok
=========================
select case 
       when A.key=B.key_1 and A.roll_no=10 then A.id 
       else null end
       as col_1 ,
       case 
       when A.key=(concat(B.key_1,'|',B.key_2)) and  A.roll_no=20 then A.id 
       else null end
       as col_2
from TABLE_A A ,TABLE_B B

Comment: @BiswaPatra please do not use `TABLE_A A ,TABLE_B B` old join syntax. It could work with the given example if you use conditional aggregation and cross join tables see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2DAEBEb_)